# How to parse a line of integers in C

Tags: c, parsing

I want to do a very basic read of each integer in the following test text file.

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

But the following code infinitely prints 1 after I correctly print the first line.

```
FILE* f;
uint32_t current_row = 0;
uint32_t current_col = 0;
char line[1024];
int value; // issues with printing uint32_t right now

// Open the file
f = fopen("blah.txt", "r");
if (f == NULL) {                                                               
  fprintf(stderr, "file could not be opened.\r\n");                    
  exit(ERROR_FILEPATH);                                                        
}

// Read in each row
while (NULL != fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
  printf("%d: %s\r\n", current_row, line);

  // Read in each integer in the current row 
  while (sscanf(line, "%d", &value) {
    printf("%d\t", value);
    // TODO: How to read a single integer in at a time?
    current_col++;
  }

  current_col = 0;
  current_row++;
}

// Close the file                                                              
if (fclose(f)) {                                                      
  fprintf(stderr, "file could not be closed.\r\n");                      
  exit(ERROR_FILECLOSE);                                                       
}
```

Comment: sidenote; "issues with printing uint32_t" -- `#include <inntypes.h>` and `printf("%" PRIu32, value);`

Comment: Also, this does not even compile. Post real code.

Comment: You should have compared it to EOF - meaning End Of File and not NULL that mentions the end of a string in C and C++ :P

Comment: @user3195614 1) Comparing with `NULL` as in `(NULL != fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)` _is_ correct - see C spec §7.21.7.2.  2) Note: `NULL` in C is the null pointer.  `'\0'` is the null character.  If using ASCII encoded `char`, `'\0'` is also an ASCII `NUL`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
  // Read in each integer in the current row 
  while (sscanf(line, "%d", &value) {
    printf("%d\t", value);
    // TODO: How to read a single integer in at a time?
    current_col++;
  }
```

*Personally, I'm not a fan of the 'scanf' functions family:*

```
  // Read in each integer in the current row 
  char *cp = line;
  while(*cp && *cp != '\n') 
    {
    /* skip leading white space. */
    while(isspace(*cp))
       ++cp;

    /* Read the next number. */   
    value = strtol(cp, &cp, 10);
    printf("%d\t", value);

    current_col++;
    }
```

Comment: the `&& *cp != '\n'` part is redundant, `isspace()` returns nonzero for `\n`.

Comment: But that's because you are not using `strtol()` properly. You should be checking its return value against 0, and if it is 0, you should check the value of `errno`. See my answer.

Comment: huh... what? I didn't assume it either, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Note: 1) `strtol()` skips leading white-space.  `while(isspace(*cp)) ++cp;` is not needed.  2) If the input line had a bad number like "x", the while loop would never terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `strtol()`, but the proper way to use it is to check its return value and `errno`:

```
const char *end = line + strlen(line);
char *endp = NULL;
const char *p = line;
while (p < end) {
    errno = 0;
    long value = strtol(p, &endp, 10);

    if (errno && (value == 0 || value == LONG_MIN || value == LONG_MAX)) {
        break;
    }

    p = endp;
    printf("%ld\t", value);
        current_col++;
    }
}
```

Also, if you are trying to print C99-style fixed width integers:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint32_t foo = 42;
printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", foo);
```

Comment: Good to check the results of `strtol()`.  `errno` is set when overflow occurs, not necessarily on other conditions such as no conversion.  With no conversion, `endp == p`.  Recommend instead `if (errno || p == endp) { break; }`

Comment: @chux checking `errno` makes the code uniform, that's why I prefer it.

Comment: @checking Per the C spec §7.22.1.4 does not require `errno` to be set if `p` was "" or "xx", thus checking if `errno` is set is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *p =line;
int len = 0;
while (sscanf(p, "%d%n", &value, &len)==1) {
    printf("%d\t", value);
    current_col++;
    p += len;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sscanf` on the line repeatedly, you have to use `strtok` to get to the next location in the string and use either `sscanf` or `atoi` on the next location in the string.

Replace

```
// Read in each integer in the current row 
while (sscanf(line, "%d", &value) {
  printf("%d\t", value);
  // TODO: How to read a single integer in at a time?
  current_col++;
}
```

by

```
  // Read in each integer in the current row 
  if (sscanf(line, "%d", &value))
  {
     current_col++;
     nextToken = strtok(line, " ");
     while (nextToken != NULL && sscanf(nextToken, "%d", &value))
     {
        current_col++;
        printf("%d\t", value);
        nextToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
     }
  }
  printf("\n");
```